# Django (proxy and abstract) add extra fields to child of a custom-user class (AbstrsactBaseUser)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database, django-custom-user

I created a custom user class that is inherited from AbstractBaseUser, this class has a chil class. The problem is I can't add new fields to the children's classes because they had (class Meta: proxy = Ture). The following error appears: `?: (models.E017) Proxy model 'StudentUser' contains model fields.`

user_model.py

```
class AppUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    objects = MyUserManager()

    username = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=64, unique=True)
        .
        .
        .


class StudentUser(AppUser):
    objects = StudentManager()

    GPA = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2) #This causes the error if proxy=True 

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.password = make_password(self.password)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

sittings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   .
   .
   .
    "app",
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "app.AppUser
```

admin.py

```
admin.site.register(AppUser)
admin.site.register(StudentUser)
```

When I remove (proxy = True) from the child and add (abstract = True) to the parent the following error appears: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'app.AppUser' that has not been installed`

user_model.py

```
class AppUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    objects = MyUserManager()

    class Meta:
         abstract = True

    username = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=64, unique=True)
        .
        .
        .


class StudentUser(AppUser):
    objects = StudentManager()

    GPA = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2) 

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.password = make_password(self.password)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

How can I extend the AppUser and add fields to the child and keep the AppUser as the user model `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "app.AppUser` ?

Comment: Your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` cannot be abstract, remove that from `AppUser.Meta`. You can have a child model of a non-abstract model although it's not clear exactly how you want this to behave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked, I deleted the class Meta for both proxy and abstract:

user_model.py

```
class AppUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    objects = MyUserManager()

    username = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=64, unique=True)
        .
        .


class StudentUser(AppUser):
    objects = StudentManager()

    GPA = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2) 

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.password = make_password(self.password)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).